# How to download PDF reports in SonarQube 7.1 Comunity Editon

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using sonarqube-7.1 version. I want to make report from sonarqube either as csv, xml or pdf. I have googled it and found that we can make pdf report using sonar-pdfreport-plugin. I have dowload the version sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4 and pasted it in the extension/pluggin folder. But I can't restart the server. Anyone please provide a solution for getting report for the version provided above.

Comment: Where did you get this plugin from? Add url as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[sonar-pdf-report](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report) is dead. The last change has been made in 2015. This plugin is of course incompatible with SonarQube 5, 6, 7 etc.

Reporting is available only in [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/):

> **Executive reporting**
>
> Gain visibility into health factors such as operational risks and security risks. Generate, export and schedule reports in PDF format to ensure visibility of key metrics to all stakeholders. Get fast reporting and up-to-date information, no matter the number of projects.